# PHP DateTime / DateInterval object difference returning strange results

Tags: php, datetime, date

I have the following [PHP datetime object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) giving strange results:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime("2013-01-01");
$date2 = new DateTime("2011-01-01");

$interval = $date2->diff($date);
echo $interval->m;
?>
```

- When using months (m), returns 0. Incorrect.
- When I switch the interval to years (y) it returns 2 which is correct.
- When I switch to days (d) it returns 0, incorrect.
- When I switch to days using "days", it returns 731 which is correct

I am not sure why certain intervals are working and others are not. Any ideas or is this expected? If possible - I would like to continue using DateTime to find this difference but an open to other necessary means.

Comment: I believe that the singluar version is for use with the other interval values (and them together), and the plural will show the differencein only that time interval

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See, `$interval` is an object, not some primitive value. In your example this interval *consists of* two years, zero months and zero days. It doesn't get automatically converted into 'interval in months, interval in days' etc. when you're querying its properties: it just returns their values. And it's quite right: should you consider 29 days interval a month interval, for example?

The only exception is `$days` property (not `$d`!), which actually has a calculated value of days in that interval. And it's quite well described in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php):

> *$days* 
> *Total* number of days between the starting and ending dates in a
> DateTime::diff() calculation

Comment: Here is a good example from the docs:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php#example-648

Comment: @raina77ow - thank you for your help. This makes perfect sense and something I was not aware of. I suppose I could simply calculate an estimated number of months based on (x days / 30.5) but it of course would not be exact. Is using something like a strtotime the only way in this manner then?

Comment: @JM4 But strtotime won't convert something like `32 days` into `a month and X days` just because it doesn't know what month is it (it's exactly the same consideration as with DateInterval::format). Or did you talk about something else?

Comment: @raina77ow - I'm just looking for something that will basically tell me: the difference in those two dates is 24 months.

Comment: @JM4 If you don't need to take the days into account, you can just get `12 * $y + $m`, I think (at least I can't imagine situation where it may give you the wrong result). With days it's way more problematic.